# Navigate to previous page using Selenium

Tags: selenium, java

I know there's a

```
driver.navigate().back()
```

but that's not what I'm looking for.

Let's say a user is on PageA, they click on a submit button which takes them to a submit page. On that page, there are two buttons: change selection and confirm. Confirm takes them to the next page, but change selection takes them back to the page they were on.

It's not always going to be PageA, a user can be on PageB, PageC, etc. So, I was wondering if there is a way to return the PageFactory of whatever page the user was previously on? I haven't been able to find anything so far

Comment: Why do you want that rather than finding the appropriate button? If you use the "Change Selection" button, you'll get all the appropriate state information held in the site, where a different method may not maintain the information and cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue; I wanted a base class for my PageObjects that abstracted the navigation between pages in the wizard flow. What I ended up doing was, after clicking any link that would navigate to a new page, I grabbed the current URL and constructed a new page instance based on that to return. Something like:

```
protected PageObject navigate(WebElement button) {
    button.click();
    PageObject nextPage = getPageFromURL(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, nextPage);
    return nextPage;
}
```

where getPageFromURL has a big lookup table of URLs to PageObject classes. Then I could implement meaningful methods like:

```
public PageObject clickNext() {
    return navigate(nextButton);
}
```

or:

```
 public PageObject viewProductDetails(Product p) {
    return navigate(getDetailsButton(p));
}
```

I hope that helps you with architecting a solution!

Answer (score 7):

You can use JavaScript to go back one step in the history of the browser, this should bring you back on the previous page.

```
driver.executeScript("window.history.go(-1)");
```

See [using JavaScript with Selenium](http://www.mkyong.com/selenium/how-to-execute-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver/) and [JavaScript History functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp) links.

Also see [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3611) about issue and difference with navigate.back()

Comment: This answer should actually be using an instance of JavascriptExecutor before the executeScript call.  Such as: `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;` Then use `js.executeScript("window.history.go(-1)");`