# I get find element error when I try to click on footer part whole link

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

**My coding logic:**

```
List<WebElement> getelement = driver
                .findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='footer__content']//a[@class='footer-nav__link']"));

        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 60000);
for (int i = 0; i < getelement.size(); i++) {                       
            System.out.println("clicking on this link::" + getelement.get(i).isDisplayed());
            getelement.get(i).click();
            Thread.sleep(15000);
            driver.navigate().back();
            Thread.sleep(30000);

        }
```

**Error is :**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.108)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'SHASHANK', ip: '169.254.91.79', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca..., userDataDir: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Loca...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 74.0.3729.108, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 844f1399541d4bb05f1922d9194602a0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed(RemoteWebElement.java:320)
    at Login.Footer_Link.main(Footer_Link.java:35)
```

Comment: It is throwing ```StaleElementReferenceException``` means on which element you wan to perform an action that element is not attached on DOM.

Comment: Also your ```WebDriverWait ``` object has been created but after the element, so your Explicit wait is also not working on this code.

Comment: Yes, I know It but when I move to back that time next link element is not getting

Comment: after click on link, does you page open on new window?

Comment: No, It's open in same page and also move to back by using browser back

By using :driver.navigate().back();

Comment: It means after navigate back it's not getting the another link.

Comment: May this help you  (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8737/navigate-to-previous-page-using-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

This does not work, you cannot click a link that loads another page. Then go back and expect the earlier found elements to still be there in memory.

```
        getelement.get(i).click();
        driver.navigate().back();
```

You need to again find the elements after back. Changed your example code a bit to retrieve the elements again in the loop.

```
By path = By.xpath("//a");
List<WebElement> elementsCount = driver.findElements(path).size();

for (int i = 0; i < elementsCount ; i++) {     
            List<WebElement> getelement = driver.findElements(path);                  
            System.out.println("clicking on this link::" + getelement.get(i).isDisplayed());
            getelement.get(i).click();
            Thread.sleep(15000);
            driver.navigate().back();
            Thread.sleep(30000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks It's resolve now.